# How to time interval between event in lua

Tags: lua

I am writing a simple script in lua. If the LED is on, it will increment the counter by 1. If the led is off for more than 1 seconds, it reset the counter.

So how exactly do we time event like that in lua ?

This is what i have and been testing multiple ways so far.

```
function ReadADC1()
    local adc_voltage_value = 0
    adc_voltage_value = tonumber(adc.readadc()) * 2 -- 0.10 --get dec number out of this -- need to know where package adc come from
    --convert to voltage
    adc_voltage_value = adc_voltage_value *0.000537109375 --get V
    adc_voltage_value = math.floor(adc_voltage_value *1000 +0.5) --since number is base off resolution

    --print (adc_voltage_value)
    return adc_voltage_value

end
-- end of readADC1() TESTED

function interval()
local counter1 =0 
ledValue = ReadADC1()
if (ledValue >= OnThreshHold) then
    ledStatus = 1
    t1=os.time()
else
    ledStatus = 0
    t2 = os.time()
end

--counter1 =0
for i=1,20 do
if (ledStatus == 1) then -- if led is off for more than 1 second, reset counter = 0
counter1 = counter1 + 1
elseif ((ledStatus ==0 and ((os.difftime(os.time(),t2)/100000) > 1000))) then -- increment counter when led is on
counter1 = 0

end
end
print (counter1)
```

end
I know for sure the logic for interval is wrong since os.time return a huge number (i assume it in psecond instead of second).

Any suggest or solution is welcome. I tried vmstarttimer and vmstoptimmer before this but not sure how it work.

EDIT:

```
function counter()

    local ledValue = ReadADC1()
        local t1 = os.clock()   
        while true do
            local t2 = os.clock()
            local dt = t2 - t1
            t1 = t2

            if ((ledValue < OnThreshHold) and (dt < 1)) then -- if led is off for less than 1 second
                ledCounter = ledCounter + 1
            elseif ((ledValue < OnThreshHold) and (dt > 1)) then-- if led is off for more than 1 second
                ledCounter = 0;
            else
                ledCounter = ledCounter
            end
            print (ledCounter)
        end

end
```

Ultimately, it will be return ledCounter instead of print counter since I will plug the value of counter to another function that will print a message correspond to the number of counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `os.clock` which returns your programs runtime since start in seconds.

> Returns an approximation of the amount in seconds of CPU time used by the program. 
>    [Source](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.clock)

This function could be used in this way.

```
local t1 = os.clock() -- begin
local t2 = os.clock() -- end
local dt = t2 - t1    -- calulate delta time

-- or looped

local t1 = os.clock() -- begin
while true do
    local t2 = os.clock() -- end
    local dt = t2 - t1    -- calulate delta time
    t1 = t2               -- reset t1

    -- use dt ...
end

-- or wait for time elapsed
-- runs until 1 second passed    

local t1 = os.clock()
while (os.clock() - t1) < 1 do
    -- do stuff while dt is smaller than 1

    -- could even reset timer (t1) to current to 
    -- repeat waiting
    -- t1 = os.clock() | ...
end

-- logic for your example

function counter()
    local time = os.clock()
    local lastLedOn = false
    local counter = 0

    while true do
        if os.clock() - time > 1.0 then
            break
        end

        if getLedValue() == on then -- replace
            time = os.clock()

            if not lastLedOn then
                lastLedOn = true
                counter = counter + 1

                -- print(counter) | or here if you want to print repeatedly
            end
        end
    end

    print(counter)
end -- was unable to test it
```

Comment: Wont this only measure the delta time for the program to execute whatever in between begin and end instead of the time between LED on and off (using edge of the pulse)

Comment: You can specify the begin and end. In my example t1 would be the begin of measurement and t2 the end. dt is the time between t1 and t2. In the looped example dt would be the time between each iteration of the loop in seconds.

Comment: can you take a look at my edited code and tell me if i understand it wrong ? It only return 0 for my counter. thank you

Comment: @JackVu I think you understand the first part wrongly. Provided a full example of the logic for your problem.